# Delphi RTTI trouble: GetPropInfo returns nil with {$METHODINFO ON}?

Tags: delphi, rtti

Is there any possibility that GetPropInfo returns nil even if the given class is declared with correct {$METHODINFO} directives.

```
  type 
  ... 
  ...
    {$METHODINFO ON}
    TMyClass = class
    private
      fField: integer;
    published
      property Field: integer read fField write fField;
    end;
    {$METHODINFO OFF}
  ...
  ...
  procedure TestRTTI;
  begin
    assert(assigned(GetPropInfo(TMyClass, 'Field')), 'WTF! No RTTI found!');
  end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gotcha! It seems the problem is hidden at the forward declaration that I overlooked. Didn't know that sneaky feature.

It seems the compiler considers only the first declaration of the class to generate RTTI or not so if you have a forward declaration like this...

```
  type 
    TMyClass = class;   
    ...    
    ...
    {$METHODINFO ON}
    TMyClass = class
    private
      fField: integer;
    published
      property Field: integer read fField write fField;
    end;
    {$METHODINFO OFF}   
    ...   
    ...   
    procedure TestRTTI;   
    begin
      assert(assigned(GetPropInfo(TMyClass, 'Field')), 'WTF! No RTTI found!');   
    end;
```

... You will get the assertion error. So, for getting the RTTI right, one needs to turn the {$METHODINFO} directive on for the forward declaration, as seen here....

```
  type 
    {$METHODINFO ON}
    TMyClass = class;   
    {$METHODINFO OFF}   
    ...    
    ...
    TMyClass = class
    private
      fField: integer;
    published
      property Field: integer read fField write fField;
    end;
    ...
```

Comment: I've come across this "feature" already, too.
BTW, it's not necesarry to turn on the full {$METHODINFO ON}, it's enough to just use {$TYPEINFO ON}, or {$M+}.

Comment: It should be noted that in Delphi 2009, the compiler adds {M+} to any class with a "published" section automatically, so this problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad that you have found a solution.  It is the same thing with `$TypeInfo` directive.  Delphi 7 help says:

> Note that if a class is forward declared, the first declaration of the class must be declared with the `$M` switch.

P.S.: `$M+/- = $TypeInfo On/Off`